# Get the last datetime in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Got in excel:

```
456781  b1  28-5-2014 10:57:09
456781  b1  28-5-2014 11:04:35
456781  b1  28-5-2014 11:06:24
456781  b1  28-5-2014 11:08:56
456781  b1  28-5-2014 11:12:07
456781  b2  28-5-2014 12:30:30
456781  b2  28-5-2014 12:39:49
456781  b2  28-5-2014 12:33:00
456781  b2  28-5-2014 12:35:05
456781  b2  28-5-2014 12:36:24
```

result i want

```
456781  b1  28-5-2014 11:12:07
456781  b2  28-5-2014 12:39:49
```

The result has to be in other worksheet

Is there Vba code to the result i want?

it tried it without de b1/b2 as code':

```
Sub test()

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B" & LastRow).FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(Sheet1!R1C[-1]:R4C[-1]=RC[-1],Sheet1!R1C:R4C))"

End Sub
```

Comment: You can do this simply with a Pivot Table

Comment: Can you help me with a Pivot table @RonRosenfeld

Answer (score 0):

you don't need macro for such purposes, this issue can be solved using array function `{max(if())}`:

1) insert criteria in column `A` (unique id);
2) insert the formula `=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$4=A8;$B$1:B$4))`, then press <kbd>ctrl+<kbd>shift</kbd>+enter</kbd> to apply `array formula` and you will get required results:

example:

[image]

---

***update***

1) This is the one of the possible solutions using VBA:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, Data As Range, dic As Object, i$, k
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Set Data = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each cl In Data
    i = cl.Value2 & "|" & cl.Offset(, 1).Value2
        If Not dic.exists(i) Then
            dic.Add i, cl.Offset(, 2).Value2
        Else
            If CDec(dic(i)) < cl.Offset(, 2).Value2 Then dic(i) = cl.Offset(, 2).Value2
        End If
    Next cl
    For Each k In dic
        Debug.Print Split(k, "|")(0), Split(k, "|")(1), Format(dic(k), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Next k
End Sub
```

test:

[image]

---

2) or it can looks like this:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim cl As Range, Data As Range, dic As Object, i$, k
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Set Data = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each cl In Data
        i = cl.Value2 & "|" & cl.Offset(, 1).Value2
        If Not dic.exists(i) Then
            dic.Add i, Evaluate("=MAX(IF(" & Data.Address & "=" & cl.Address & _
                                    ",IF(" & Data.Offset(, 1).Address & "=" & cl.Offset(, 1).Address & _
                                       "," & Data.Offset(, 2).Address & ")))")
        End If
    Next cl
    For Each k In dic
        Debug.Print Split(k, "|")(0), Split(k, "|")(1), Format(dic(k), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Next k
End Sub
```

test:
[image]

---

3) same as previous variant but it does the output to the new workbook

```
Sub test3()
    Dim cl As Range, Data As Range, dic As Object, i$, k
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Set Data = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each cl In Data
        i = cl.Value2 & "|" & cl.Offset(, 1).Value2
        If Not dic.exists(i) Then
            dic.Add i, Evaluate("=MAX(IF(" & Data.Address & "=" & cl.Address & _
                                    ",IF(" & Data.Offset(, 1).Address & "=" & cl.Offset(, 1).Address & _
                                       "," & Data.Offset(, 2).Address & ")))")
        End If
    Next cl
    '//below the code does output of the result to the new Workbook
    Dim r&: r = 1: Workbooks.Add
    For Each k In dic
        Cells(r, "A").Value2 = Split(k, "|")(0)
        Cells(r, "B").Value2 = Split(k, "|")(1)
        Cells(r, "C").Value2 = Format(dic(k), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        r = r + 1
    Next k
End Sub
```

also such tasks can be solved by VBA using `SQL` query (e.g. Adodb), `Pivot`, `array`, `collection` and other methods.

Comment: `=If()` formula True part also have to absolute reference like `=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$4=A8;$B$1:$B$4))`

Comment: @harun24hr nice catch, sure it must be, I just forgot to specify that, thank you;)

Comment: thank you.. a edit my question with some real data, i like a macro because is has to go automatic

Comment: @Vasily, i can get it to write it to the sheet, errors, do you have a idea?

Comment: @dave see updated post (variant 3), is this what you asking for?

Comment: @Vasily, yes bi also tried this, but i got errors like type mismatch

Comment: @dave I have tested the code based on data provided in your post, and have no any errors, but anyway, please provide a little bit more details. In which row of the code you have an error? show me your final code and the data sample that you've used to see the problem behind

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using a Pivot Table.
I labelled the columns arbitrarily:

[image]

- Drag Number and Type to the Rows area
- Drag Time to the Values area
- Change the Value Field settings for Time to "MAX" and format the values
- Remove the Totals and Subtotals options from the Pivot Table Options
- Change Report Layout to show in Tabular form and Repeat all Item Labels
- And there are many more formatting options to design.

[image]

Comment: I think the datime from the dbf is strange, i get  values as: 45671 v1 28-5-2014 12:47:00 and 45672 s1 41676,57.

Comment: @dave. You probably need to format properly.  Leary how excel stores dates and times.

Comment: @Rosenfeld, is there  option  to this automatic. The data come by a macro and the table have to change if data is new

Comment: @dave  Have the macro that brings the data refresh the Pivot Table.  Look at the Pivot Table tools ribbon -- you'll see a refresh or update data button.  Record a macro to see the commands you'll need.